# How to group by Date array of DateTime in pure Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of datetime objects and i need to group objects by Date (day). How can I do t with pure ruby, without gems? For example, i have array

```
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T01:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,27000s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T01:45:00-06:00 ((2457086j,27900s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T04:00:00-06:00 ((2457086j,36000s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T06:15:00-06:00 ((2457086j,44100s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-03T07:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,48600s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T10:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,59400s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T11:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,63000s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-02T14:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,73800s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T16:00:00-06:00 ((2457086j,79200s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
```

And i need to group like

```
#<DateTime: 2015-03-02T14:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,73800s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
-----------
#<DateTime: 2015-03-03T07:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,48600s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
-----------
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T01:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,27000s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T01:45:00-06:00 ((2457086j,27900s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T04:00:00-06:00 ((2457086j,36000s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T06:15:00-06:00 ((2457086j,44100s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T10:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,59400s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T11:30:00-06:00 ((2457086j,63000s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
#<DateTime: 2015-03-04T16:00:00-06:00 ((2457086j,79200s,0n),-21600s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Could you provide some simple extract from your `array` of `datetime` objects?

Comment: @CAMOKPYT Not here.. In your question itself. :)

Comment: Do you want to group the entries by day (4) or by date (2015-03-04)?

Comment: by Date, 10.10.2015 and 10.10.2014 should be different, the only thing i need to ignore is Time, 10.10.2015:10.05.15 and 10.10.2015:12.05.05 should be in one group

Comment: @CAMOKPYT you can edit your question to clarify it. Explain your requirements, show the desired output and describe what you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
require 'date'

# if you want day of the month 
array_of_datetimes.group_by(&:day)
# if you want the day of week 
array_of_datetimes.group_by(&:wday)
```

Look at the method [`Date#day`](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-day).

Well, as [Stefan addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850935/how-to-group-by-day-array-of-datetime-in-pure-ruby/28850979?noredirect=1#comment45970004_28850979), OP wanted something else. But I didn't get it from the question of OP. Anyway, this is what the OP wanted finally :

```
array_of_datetimes.group_by(&:to_date)
```

Comment: The OP is [actually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850935/how-to-group-by-day-array-of-datetime-in-pure-ruby#comment45969954_28850935) looking for `group_by(&:to_date)`

Comment: @Stefan Dunno.. I parsed this line _i need to group objects by day_  in my code.. :)

Comment: @Stefan yes, to_date is better for my needs, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` from `Enumerable` module. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by for more detail.

```
array.group_by do |datetime|
  "#{datetime.year}#{datetime.month}#{datetime.day}"
end
# => { "2015-03-03" => [...], "2015-03-04" => [...] }
```